# Slide Show Titles

Tags: presentation

I have a question about the proper way to format a title. If I have a slide with the following title, "Motivation". Then suppose on the next slide I have the same title, "Motivation".

What is the proper way to number this? For the first slide would it be, "Motivation (1)"? And on the second slide "Motivation (2)"?

Comment: Whatever is is clearest for the audience. If you can find a more descriptive title, use that.

Comment: Disagree with the hold.  It is a reasonable question.  The question does not have a digital x=1 answer, but I would not really label it as opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could number them any way you think is clear and helpful, e.g. "Motivation (2)", "Motivation (2/456)", or use more descriptive titles, or granular subheadings: "Motivation: History of numbering schemes". Note that it's also reasonable to not bother with such subdivisions. If three slides would fall under the heading of "Introduction", then they can all be labeled that - similarly to how several paragraphs in a paper could fall under that heading. If they're paying any attention, people will notice when you change slide anyway, and it's not like "(2)" adds much to the audience. It can be worthwhile to have a running slide number in the bottom corner, if you want each slide to have a unique identifier, but it's no requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In slideware (PPT) documents, I will use a format like this for titles of things that can't be broken into separate topics and stretch over more than one slide:

- Problems with moderators at ASE (1 of 3)
- Problems with moderators at ASE (2 of 3)
- Problems with moderators at ASE (3 of 3)

I do this routinely in the work world and see others do the same.  So I think it works and is normal.

In general, I try to have different topics, titles.  So if you can, great.  But there are times where it would be too awkward to do this and it is just better to use the (1 of x) format.  For example, if you have a numbered list stretching over pages and not easily separated into sublists.  I prefer (1 of x) versus just (1) because audience can see where going.

You should also always number your slides on a PPT.  But that is different from title issue.  Is for whole document and is small and usually at bottom.  Will not display in projection mode but is useful when printing the document or working with it.  (Of course this does not apply to transparencies or slides in a carousel.  Here the whole point is the flexibility to mix/match.)